# Writing systemd script

Tags: boot, 16.04, systemd, init

I have a process that I need to run at startup. It is something that needs to stay running the entire time that the machine is on. As of now I am just typing the following into bash everything I start my server.

```
command -f argument & disown
```

I know that I need to make an init script, but I had no idea how. After some research, it seems Ubuntu uses systemd (some references said Upstart, they aren't the same right?) as its init system. But all the guides I found online tell me to place my executable in `/etc/init` or `/etc/init.d`. Init is supposed to be a completely different init system.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? A sample systemd script or even an online guide would be a great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two files:

1. Your script file:

   ```
   command.sh
   ```
2. The `.service` file to be placed in `/etc/systemd/system` and given permission of `644` with `chmod 664 command.service`:

   ```
   command.service
   ```
3. The simplest content of `command.service` would be:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Some service description

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/path/to/command.sh -f argument & disown"

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
4. Now to make it launch at boot we use the `systemd` controller `systemctl`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable command

   # or 

   sudo systemctl enable command.service
   ```

Note many more options are available for the various sections, see [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), and make sure your `command.sh` is executable with `chmod +x command.sh`

Comment: 2 questions: 1. `&` and `disown` are bash specific. Do I need to write `/bin/bash -c "command -f argument & disown"` or will what you have suffice?

Comment: yes that would since it's a script...

Comment: Have you considered using `Session and Startup -> Application Autostart` ?

Comment: Including "&" and "disown" should not be necessary, as systemd already runs the command in the background it' snot attached to a shell session.  Review `man systemd.service` to confirm the `Type=` is appropriate for your service.   Then since you don't need "&" and "disown", you should be able to execute the command directly, rather than via Bash.

Comment: @WillemK I am not running a GUI, but otherwise I would do that

Comment: Question 2: since `command` is an executable, not a script, do I need to make a wrapper script for it or could I just call the executable itself from systemd

Comment: If you want to it's up to you